# Imitating Photoshop's layer mask

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to remove the background of an image using a mask where the alpha value of a pixel is proportional to the black intensity. For instance, given the following input image and mask, the result contains "faded" areas:

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]

Note the faded areas. Basically I'm trying to imitate the layer mask function in Photoshop.

I'm able to turn the mask into alpha using binary threshold, but I wonder how to make the alpha proportional. The code for binary threshold is as follows:

```py
    mask = cv2.imread(mask_path, 0)
    mask2 = np.where(mask<50, 0, 1).astype('uint8')

    img = img * mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]

    _, alpha = cv2.threshold(mask2, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    png = np.dstack((img, alpha))
    cv2.imwrite(dest_path, png)
```

I suppose it may perhaps be irrelevant as thresholds are probably not needed for layer masking.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "make the alpha proportional". When you binarize properly, you can get rid of the faded areas. What do you want to happen. Please show an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can get the proportional effect by subtracting the values of the mask from the image. That means you have to invert the mask, so the amount of alpha you want to remove is white. For `subtract()`, the input arrays need to have the same size, so convert the inverted mask to 3 color channels. If the size of the mask is not equal to the background image, you'll first have to create a subimage.

[image]

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

# load background image
img = cv2.imread('grass.jpg')
# load alpha mask as grayscale
mask = cv2.imread('a_mask.jpg',0)
# invert mask and convert to 3 color channels
mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
fullmask = cv2.cvtColor(mask,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# create a subimage with the size of the mask
xOffset = 30
yOffset = 30
height, width = mask.shape[:2]
subimg = img[yOffset:yOffset+height,xOffset:xOffset+width]

#subtract mask values from subimage
res = cv2.subtract(subimg,fullmask)

# put subimage back in background
img[yOffset:yOffset+height,xOffset:xOffset+width] = res

#display result
cv2.imshow('Result',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```